# How to retrieve a file name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I get it so that when the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, then in the cancel button function where it contains the variable var image_file_name, it retrieves the name of the file which was entered within the file input? Then hopefully the $GET method in the cancelimage.php page can be used to retrieve the file name from the function?

Below is my attempt but it is not retrieving a file name. It is just retrieving a blank.

Below is the form code and javascript function which controls the "Cancel" button:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' 
      method='post'enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return 
      startImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' ><label>" + 

"Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/>
<br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 

"<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload'/>  
</label>" + 

"<input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel'/>
</label>" + 

"<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>")
```

...

```
 var _cancelimagecounter = cancelimagecounter;


    $(".imageCancel").click(function() {
    var image_file_name = <?php echo json_encode($image_file_name); ?>;

    jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php?fileImage=" + image_file_name)
        .done(function(data) {

        $(".imagemsg" + _cancelimagecounter).html(data);
    });

    return stopImageUpload();

});
```

Below is the cancelimage.php script where it uses the $GET method to get the file name from the var image_file_name:

```
<?php

...

$image_file_name = $_GET["fileImage"];

    echo "File Upload was Canceled";

        $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
        WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($image_file_name)."'";

    mysql_query($imagecancelsql);

    mysql_close();


?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Normally, if you have cancelled the upload there should be no image in the DB.

Comment: @PedroFerreira The problem I have is that when the user does cancel the upload, the name is still displayed in the database when it shouldn;t be. But the reason it is stored in the database is because I have stated that if the "Upload" button is clicked, then insert name of file in a database row. But what I want to do is that if the user has clicked on the "Cancel" button, then delete the row of the file name which has just been inserted. Does that make sense?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer When a file is cancelled I have been able to do it so that the file does not get uploaded onto server. The problem I have is mentioned in the comment I written above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filename is far form the issue here.... But your fileName is not displaying because you are trying to use `$_GET["fileImage"];`

The Form was submitted via `enctype='multipart/form-data` and `<input name='fileImage' type='file'`

You should use `$_FILES` instead ...

Your file name would be

```
$image_file_name = $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ;
```

Comment: thanks for the info, do I need to change anything in the cancel button function in the javascript code as well or shall I leave it as it is?

Comment: The question is why are you outputting so much code with JavaScript when u can just hide or display it